# How can I have the wait_for command run multiple times in one run?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
msg = await ctx.channel.send(f"`Now playing: {var3}` \n{url}")
await msg.add_reaction(u"\u23F8")
await msg.add_reaction(u"\u25B6")
while True:
  try:
    reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=lambda reaction, user: reaction.emoji in [u"\u23F8", u"\u25B6"], timeout=90.0)
  
  except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    return await msg.clear_reactions()
  
  else:
    if reaction.emoji == u"\u23F8":
      await msg.remove_reaction(reaction.emoji, ctx.author)
      await ctx.voice_client.pause()
    elif reaction.emoji == u"\u25B6":
      await msg.remove_reaction(reaction.emoji, ctx.author)
      await ctx.voice_client.resume()
```

This is a snippet of code from a play command, it's supposed send a message showing what is playing, and bring up pause and play reactions which will pause and play the audio when reacted to by a user. Right now it only runs once during a run of the whole code, this means it will only respond the first time a user calls the command and does a reaction. For example, if a user plays something then pauses through the pause reaction it will pause, but if he then does the play reaction right after he will get no response. Likewise, if he plays another song after the first one and tries pausing or playing through the reaction he will get no response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is wrap the reaction handler under a `asyncio.create_task()`, this'll prevent these code from blocking the `wait_for()`.

```
import asyncio

msg = await ctx.channel.send(f"`Now playing: {var3}` \n{url}")
await msg.add_reaction("\u23F8")
await msg.add_reaction("\u25B6")
while True:
  try:
    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add",
                                        check=lambda reaction, user:
                                        user.id == ctx.author.id and
                                        reaction.message.id == msg.id and
                                        reaction.emoji in ["\u23F8", "\u25B6"],
                                        timeout=90.0)

  
  except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    return await msg.clear_reactions()
  
  async def process():
    if reaction.emoji == "\u23F8":
      await msg.remove_reaction(reaction.emoji, ctx.author)
      await ctx.voice_client.pause()
    elif reaction.emoji == "\u25B6":
      await msg.remove_reaction(reaction.emoji, ctx.author)
      await ctx.voice_client.resume()

  asyncio.create_task(process())
```

In addition to using `create_task()`, your `wait_for` check should include checking for the same user and same message. Otherwise someone else could be reacting to some message with these two emojis and your `wait_for` will think its valid. Also, unicode strings `u"..."` no longer requires the `u` prefix, in Python 3 all strings are unicode by default.

Comment: It works but I get an error after every time I react, doesn't seem to affect anything though because everything continues to work after. Here's the error: 
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-66' coro=<play.<locals>.process() done, defined at h:\name\Documents\discord\bot\bot.py:214> exception=TypeError("object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:\name\Documents\discord\bot\bot.py", line 217, in process
    await ctx.voice_client.pause()
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: @ZT255 Ah, it's because `ctx.voice_client.pause()` and `ctx.voice_client.resume()` isn't coroutines, you need to remove the `await` in front of it.